# Handle/catch RuntimeWarnings in connection with igraph python

Tags: python, warnings, igraph, try-except

I am running the code

```
testgraph = igraph.Graph.Degree_Sequence(degseq,method = "vl")
```

which sometimes throws the warning

```
RuntimeWarning: Cannot shuffle graph, maybe there is only a single one? at gengraph_graph_molloy_hash.cpp:332
```

I would like to catch this warning, so I can stop working with degree sequences that only have one graph.

I tried

```
degseq = [1,2,2,3]
try:
    testgraph = igraph.Graph.Degree_Sequence(degseq,method = "vl")
except RuntimeWarning:
    print degseq
else:
    print "go on"
```

which returns the warning and then "go on".

I tried upgrading the warning to an exception with

```
warnings.simplefilter('error', 'Cannot shuffle graph')
degseq = [1,2,2,3]
try:
    testgraph = igraph.Graph.Degree_Sequence(degseq,method = "vl")
except RuntimeWarning:
    print degseq
else:
    print "go on"
```

among others, and now something weird happens! It returns

```
testgraph = igraph.Graph.Degree_Sequence(degseq,method = "vl")
MemoryError: Error at src/attributes.c:284: not enough memory to allocate attribute hashes, Out of memory
```

How do I make python catch the RuntimeWarning? And why does the new exception occur when I upgrade the warning to an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to catch all warnings during an igraph call:

```
from warnings import catch_warnings
with catch_warnings(record=True) as caught_warnings:
    testgraph = igraph.Graph.Degree_Sequence(degseq, method="vl")
    if caught_warnings:
        # caught_warnings is a list of warnings; do something with them here
```

Regarding the `MemoryError` that you see: it is actually a bug in the Python interface of igraph. Internally, the C core of the igraph library (which does not know anything about the host language it is embedded in) raises a warning for your degree sequence. This is then turned into a Python warning, which is then turned into an exception by your warning handler. However, the C core of the igraph library does not anticipate that igraph core warnings are sometimes turned into exceptions so it happily proceeds with the execution of the code for `Graph.Degree_Sequence`, notices the warning-that-was-turned-into-an-exception a few internal calls later, and wrongly attributes it to the failure of some other memory allocation (that has nothing to do with your original warning).

Comment: I have added a bug report to the issue tracker of `python-igraph` regarding the `MemoryError`: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/38